# iOS Mapbox SDK cannot create Exp(.all) from array of inputs

Tags: swift, mapbox-ios

I have a geojson with a thousand of features with different properties.
Some properties are arrays like: `options: [foo, bar, buz]`.
And i need to filter features by values from these arrays, but i stuck on the building filters dynamically in runtime.

For filtering I trying to use the next expression:

```
layer.filter = Exp(.all) {
    Exp(.get) { "foo" }
    Exp(.get) { "bar" }
}
```

Everything working fine. But i don't understand how to create this expression from array of inputs? I tried to map array to filters like:

```
layer.filter = Exp(.all) {
    ["foo", "bar"].map { filter in
        Exp(.get) { filter }
    }
}
```

and i got error:

```
Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [RootCodingKeys(stringValue: "filter", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

I cannot find any docs or samples how to build `.all` expression in Mapbox iOS SDK.
I know that it's possible, to create filter like this on Android, but what is the correct way to implement it on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the correct way:

```
Expression(
    operator: .all,
    arguments: ["foo", "bar"].map { filter in 
        Expression.Argument.expression(Exp(.get) { filter })
    }
)
```